# Create a new tag or edit the existing tag

Tags: support

I've created a new tag "LinuxOnAzure". But it seems that the superuser doesn't allow the upper case in tags. So the tag becomes "linuxonazure". It's not good for reading.

I would like to change it to "linux-on-azure". But the system tells me that the tag "linux-on-azure" is same as "LinuxOnAzure".

Is there anyway to edit the existing tag or create the new tag with "linux-on-azure"?

Update： Here is the error information

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You might want to fill up the tag wiki/tag wiki exerpt. That would do wonders for understanding what the tag is about. I'll need to go look up what's the rules for tags now

Comment: If you click on any tag and then click on the synonym link, you get to a page like this: http://superuser.com/tags/linux-on-azure/synonyms, where it suggests adding synonym tags to make it easier for users to find the tag.  To use the built-in feature, your need more than 2500 rep and an answer score of 5 or more on the tag.  Otherwise, you can suggest it on Meta like you did here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[linux-on-azure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-on-azure) tag created and merged with [linuxonazure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linuxonazure)

Feel free to ensure the tag wiki/excerpts are filled up since they're a lot more useful than just the name

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll update the excerpts later.